# Error message : Field require API Level 11 (current min is 9) : android .os.AsynTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, android-asynctask, lint

I am using the `AsyncTask` to do network operation and set the `minSDKVersion` to 8. I am trying to execute the `AsyncTask` like how, it gives red line error then I need to clean the project everytime then it works.

```
downloadAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

To avoid these errors What I can do for this ?

Here see the screenshot what is the use of these @SuppressLint, @TargetAPI,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That method (`executeOnExecutor()`) and that field (`THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`) were added in API Level 11. Your `minSdkVersion` is 9, and so some devices that you run on will not have that method or field, and you will crash.

Either raise your `minSdkVersion` to 11, or only use `executeOnExecutor()` on new-enough devices:

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  static public <T> void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task,
                                          T... params) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    }
    else {
      task.execute(params);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Here see the screenshot in the question what is the use of these SuppressLint, TargetAPI annotation tags

Comment: @Williams: Do not use `@SuppressLint()`. You have a real problem. You need to fix the real problem.  All using `@SuppressLint` will do is allow your app to compile, then crash on API Level 9-10 devices. My sample `executeAsyncTask()` method is one way of fixing the problem. There are others.

Comment: Yes I am doing in same way but don't know what does mean of SuppressLint and TargetAPI. Can you please explain about the `TargetAPI` annotation also ?

Comment: @Williams `TargetAPI` means: I understand this piece of code should only run on API 11 and up and I promise that's the only case this code will be run. `SuppressLint` means: don't bother me with that, I don't care.

Comment: @Budius Suppose `minSDKVersion` is 8 and I set the `TargetAPI` annotation to JELLY_BEAN to entire method and I call that method in my `Activity` so will this method call or work in Android 2.2 or 2.3 phones ?

Comment: @Williams: I do not know what "this method" is. You cannot call `executeOnExecutor()` on Android 2.2 or 2.3 phones. The `executeAsyncTask()` helper method in my answer can be used on all versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare see for example this method http://pastebin.com/2qPcjFG0 Suppose minSDKVersion is 8 and I set the TargetAPI annotation to HONEY_COMB to entire method and I call that method in my Activity so will this method call or work in Android 2.2 or 2.3 phones ?

Comment: @Williams: That method is empty. The `@TargetApi()` annotation does not allow methods to work. It simply tells the build tools that you fixed your bug.

Comment: @CommonsWare if there is code which honeycomb supports then ?

Comment: @Williams: Then you have a bug which you did not fix. Let me try bold caps: **YOU CANNOT CALL METHODS THAT DO NOT EXIST**. `executeOnExecutor()` and "code which honeycomb supports" do not exist before API Level 11. You need to use an `if` statement or something, like in the code I have in my answer, to *only* call "code which honeycomb supports" on API Level 11+ devices. Then, and only then, do you add the `@TargetApi()` annotation to tell the build tools that you are correctly handling all API levels.

Comment: @Williams: See also http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes http://developer.android.com/training/search/backward-compat.html#check-ver

Comment: @CommonsWare OK thanks :) calm down :) +1 always helpful your answers